# Trouble understanding yield in C#

Tags: c#, .net, yield, yield-return

I'm hoping to get some clarification on a snippet that I've recently stepped through in the debugger, but simply cannot really understand.

I'm taking a **C#** course on **PluralSight** and the current topic is on `yield` and returning a `IEnumerable<T>` with the keyword.

I've got this overly basic function that returns an `IEnumerable` collection of `Vendors` (A simple class with `Id`, `CompanyName` and `Email`):

```
public IEnumerable<Vendor> RetrieveWithIterator()
{
    this.Retrieve(); // <-- I've got a breakpoint here
    foreach(var vendor in _vendors)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"Vendor Id: {vendor.VendorId}");
        yield return vendor;
    }
}
```

And I've got this code in a unit test that I'm using to test the function:

```
var vendorIterator = repository.RetrieveWithIterator(); // <-- Why don't it enter function?
foreach (var item in vendorIterator) // <-- But starts here?
{
    Debug.WriteLine(item);
}
var actual = vendorIterator.ToList();
```

What I really can't seem to understand, and I'm sure a lot of beginners are having the same trouble, is why the initial call to `RetrieveWithIterator` doesn't initiate the function, but it rather starts when we start iterating through its returned `IEnumerable` collection (see the comments).

Comment: yield is all about defered execution (stream like)

Comment: You missed the [Deferred execution](https://www.kenneth-truyers.net/2016/05/12/yield-return-in-c/)

Comment: Cheers. Do you have any good, easy-to-understand sources that I can use to read up on it? I'd love to edit the question with it, as I'm sure other people might be having the same troubles as I have

Comment: [Another example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37856965/4137916) of an iterator getting dissected, with references to the standard.

Comment: we call this Deferred and lazy execution, see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2515796/deferred-execution-and-eager-evaluation

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is called deferred execution, `yield` is lazy and will only work as much as it needs to.

This has great many advantages, one of which being that you can create seemingly infinite enumerations:

```
public IEnumerable<int> InfiniteOnes()
{
     while (true)
         yield 1;
}
```

Now imagine that the following:

```
var infiniteOnes = InfiniteOnes();
```

Would execute eagerly, you'd have a `StackOverflow` exception coming your way quite happily.

On the other hand, because its lazy, you can do the following:

```
var infiniteOnes = InfiniteOnes();
//.... some code
foreach (var one in infiniteOnes.Take(100)) { ... }
```

And later,

```
foreach (var one in infiniteOnes.Take(10000)) { ... }
```

Iterator blocks will run only when they need to; when the enumeration is iterated, not before, not after.

Comment: Ah, interesting stuff. So the mentioned loops would basically return 100 and 1000 ones?

Comment: @geostocker yes, that is correct.

Comment: @geostocker Also, do realize that all `System.Linq` is built lazy. `infiniteOnes.Take(100)` is also lazy, so the resulting enumeration of the first 100 ones will only really execute once its enumerated in the `foreach`. The lazy chain can go on endlessly (`infiniteOnes.Take(100).Skip(10)`, etc.), it will only really start doing work when iterated.

Answer (score 5):

From msdn:

## Deferred Execution

Deferred execution means that the evaluation of an expression is delayed until its realized value is actually required. Deferred execution can greatly improve performance when you have to manipulate large data collections, especially in programs that contain a series of chained queries or manipulations. In the best case, deferred execution enables only a single iteration through the source collection.

Deferred execution is supported directly in the C# language by the yield keyword (in the form of the yield-return statement) when used within an iterator block. Such an iterator must return a collection of type `IEnumerator` or `IEnumerator<T>` (or a derived type).

```
var vendorIterator = repository.RetrieveWithIterator(); // <-- Lets deferred the execution
foreach (var item in vendorIterator) // <-- execute it because we need it
{
    Debug.WriteLine(item);
}
var actual = vendorIterator.ToList();
```

## Eager vs. Lazy Evaluation

When you write a method that implements deferred execution, you also have to decide whether to implement the method using lazy evaluation or eager evaluation.

- In lazy evaluation, a single element of the source collection is processed during each call to the iterator. This is the typical way in which iterators are implemented.
- In eager evaluation, the first call to the iterator will result in the entire collection being processed. A temporary copy of the source collection might also be required.

Lazy evaluation usually yields better performance because it distributes overhead processing evenly throughout the evaluation of the collection and minimizes the use of temporary data. Of course, for some operations, there is no other option than to materialize intermediate results.

[source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/deferred-execution-and-lazy-evaluation-in-linq-to-xml)

Answer (score 2):

It will get the items when you loop over them when needed. This way say you only need the first 4 results and then you break, it won't yield anything more and you just saved some processing power!

**From [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/yield):**

> You use a yield return statement to return each element one at a time.
>   You consume an iterator method by using a foreach statement or LINQ query. Each iteration of the foreach loop calls the iterator method. When a yield return statement is reached in the iterator method, expression is returned, and the current location in code is retained. Execution is restarted from that location the next time that the iterator function is called.
>   You can use a yield break statement to end the iteration.

*Note* - If you `.ToList()` on the result of a method that yields, it will work as if you returned a single list, thus defeating the purpose of yield.